# Import csv as MATLAB struct

Tags: matlab, csv, file, import

I have a large csv log file. Here is a simplified sample:

```
ts,a.b.c,a.b.d,a.b.e,b.c,b.d,c.d.e,c.d.f,c.g
2021-03-29 06:38:39,1.0000,2,3,28.20,1,2,3,4
2021-03-29 06:38:40,1.0000,2,3,28.20,1,2,3,0.000000
```

I am using MATLAB's Import Data tool to import it, but, unfortunately, it removes all dots from the header and imports all variables as, e.g.: abc, abd, abe etc.

What is an efficient way to import a csv like the one above as structs?
It am looking for a way to have data imported as structs: a, b and c for this particular log file, so that I can easily access variables as a.b.c or c.d.f.

Comment: Write a mapping function `[ts, a, b, c] = readData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, by simply using readtable.

```
function res = log_import(logfile)

log_table = readtable(logfile);

res = [];

for i = 1:width(log_table)
    str_path = log_table.Properties.VariableDescriptions{i};
    fields  = strsplit(str_path,'.');  
    res = setfield(res, fields{1:end}, log_table{:, i});
end

end
```